# Apply Zoom in, zoom out functionality to imageView in a PagerView

Tags: android, image, android-fragments, android-viewpager, zooming

I have a viewPager in which i have fragments in each of the pager page, i want to add zoom in, zoom out functionality to the imageView that lies in the fragment that i am showing in the viewPager.

Thanks in advance ...

Answer (score 1):

Use the PhotoView library, which is better for your need.

1. It also provides very decent function of swipe in ViewPager even after zoom-in/zoom-out.
2. And zoom-in/zoom-out in this library is upto minimum/maximum limit.

Link is:

https://github.com/chrisbanes/PhotoView/blob/master/sample/src/main/java/uk/co/senab/photoview/sample/HackyViewPager.java

Comment: yes i have by using this code and another a combination of both